# Joing lists containing Hebrew in Tcl?

Tags: sqlite, tcl, hebrew

I'm using Tcl 8.6.11, SQLite 3.35.5., and Manjaro Linux KDE.

I'm trying to take a verse in Hebrew and write it one word per row in a data table. This is one
verse, for example.

בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָֽרֶץ׃

The goal was to write the data to a list and then join the list as the values part of a SQL insert statement. As you can see, each `[lindex $l n]` prints as expected but the `[join $l ,]` starting at the second element places the Hebrew in the first position instead of the last, causing the SQL statement to fail.

How can I get each component of the `[join $l ,]` to be ordered as they are in the `[lindex $l n]`?

Thank you.

```
set l {}
set sql { select * from src_original where type_no=0 and book_no < 40 limit 1}
dbws eval $sql origLang {
  set i 0
  foreach { x } $origLang(original) { lappend l "($origLang(book_no),$origLang(chapter_no),$origLang(verse_no),[incr i],$x)" }
}

puts [lindex $l 0]; # (1,1,1,1,בְּרֵאשִׁית)
puts [lindex $l 1]; # (1,1,1,2,בָּרָא)
puts [lindex $l 2]; # (1,1,1,3,אֱלֹהִים)
puts [lindex $l 3]; # (1,1,1,4,אֵת)
puts [lindex $l 4]; # (1,1,1,5,הַשּׁמַיִם)
puts [lindex $l 5]; # (1,1,1,6,וְאֵת)
puts [lindex $l 6]; # (1,1,1,7,הָאָֽרֶץ׃)

set v [join $l ,]; # (1,1,1,1,בְּרֵאשִׁית),(1,1,1,2,בָּרָא),(1,1,1,3,אֱלֹהִים),(1,1,1,4,אֵת),(1,1,1,5,הַשּׁמַיִם),(1,1,1,6,וְאֵת),(1,1,1,7,הָאָֽרֶץ׃)

set r "insert into vowel_pts (book_no, chapter_no, verse_no, index_no, word) values $v"
dbws eval $r
```

---

Thank you for examples and suggestions.  I'd still like to understand whether or not `join` resulted in an out of order SQL statement, but, after looking at the SQL provided by @Shawn, I tried using the SQLite JSON extension and the following also works.  If the limitations in the `where` clause of the `arr_vp` table are removed, such that all the words from every verse in the thirty-nine books of the Old Testament are written as an individual row, it completes in a few seconds on my ten-year old average laptop, as @DonalFellows suggested.  Thanks again.

```
with
arr_vp as (
select book_no, chapter_no, verse_no,
       '["' || replace(original,' ', '","' ) || '"]' as t
from src_original
where book_no=1
  and chapter_no=1
  and verse_no < 3
  and type_no=0
)

select a.book_no, a.chapter_no, a.verse_no,
       (key+1) as index_no,
       j.value as vowel_pts
from arr_vp a,
     json_each( ( select t
                  from arr_vp r
                  where r.book_no=a.book_no
                    and r.chapter_no=a.chapter_no
                    and r.verse_no=a.verse_no ) ) as j
where j.type = 'text';
```

Comment: You're building strings to insert stuff into a database? Where those strings come from the database? That's _got_ to be a DB antipattern in any language!

Comment: @DonalFellow Correct. I couldn't figure out how to split the words from each verse in SQLite directly. If an insert is added in the above foreach, the correct data is written but it is very slow and has to perform about 500,000 individual inserts.  I thought I could speed it up by building a string of multiple values to reduce the number of inserts.  I was hoping then to create a table of unique words and store a list of all the locations at which each occurs in order to make searching on words, sets of words, exact phrases quicker by comparing lists rather than searching the table again.

Comment: You might want to use a left-to-right mark (LMR) explicitly to control for rendering in text of mixed direction: `set v [join $l "\u200e,"]`. Note this does not solve your problem(s), it rather aligns your visual impression and expectations.

Comment: @mrcalvin Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll try that out because it has been a bit annoying trying to work with Hebrew mixed in with English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always with SQL, use parameters in a prepared statement instead of trying to add values directly into a query string at runtime. Something like:

```
# Populate an array of dicts
set l {}
set sql {select * from src_original where type_no=0 and book_no < 40 limit 1}
dbws eval $sql origLang {
    set i 0
    foreach x $origLang(original) {
        lappend l [dict create book_no $origLang(book_no) \
                               chapter_no $origLang(chapter_no) \
                               verse_no $origLang(verse_no) \
                               index_no [incr i] \
                               word $x]
    }
}

# And insert them one at a time.
foreach w $l {
    dict with w {
        dbws eval {
            INSERT INTO vowel_pts(book_no, chapter_no, verse_no, index_no, word)
            VALUES ($book_no, $chapter_no, $verse_no, $index_no, $word)
        }
    }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#eval) for more about embedding (unevaluated) variable names in a SQL statement and binding values to them.

---

I did manage to come up with a way to do it in just core Sqlite3, assuming a standard space character separates words, that I think will work:

```
dbws eval {
    WITH verse AS (SELECT * FROM src_original WHERE type_no = 0 AND book_no < 40 LIMIT 1),
    words AS
      (SELECT book_no, chapter_no, verse_no,
              substr(original || ' ', 1, instr(original || ' ', ' ') - 1) AS word,
              substr(original || ' ', instr(original || ' ', ' ') + 1) AS original,
              1 AS index_no
       FROM verse
       UNION ALL
       SELECT book_no, chapter_no, verse_no,
              substr(original, 1, instr(original, ' ') - 1),
              substr(original, instr(original, ' ') + 1),
              index_no + 1
       FROM words WHERE length(original) > 0)
    INSERT INTO vowel_pts(book_no, chapter_no, verse_no, index_no, word)
    SELECT book_no, chapter_no, verse_no, index_no, word FROM words
}
```

Comment: If Sqlite came with a built in table-like function to split a sentence into words, you could probably do it all in a single SQL query (I have an extension that includes just such a beast...)

Comment: You can add custom functions from Tcl code.

Comment: @DonalFellows It doesn't support creating new loadable extensions in tcl, which is what's needed for a table-valued function (They're implemented as virtual tables)

Comment: I'd have done it as a pair of functions, one to get the number of words and the other to get the n'th word. Yes, a TVF would be better, but the exposure of those is not great.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you. I'll try these out.  I was trying to avoid performing an insert for every word just because I want to write all the words which are around 500,000.  Perhaps it makes no difference.  Being a novice I thought it would be better to insert them in large groups.

Comment: @Gary Just wrap everything in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The `join` command does not alter the order of characters in memory. However, the rendering of mixed left-to-right and right-to-left scripts on the screen is… well, all over the place.

But since you're just doing this to move data from the database to the database, find a way to not bring the data itself into Tcl. It'll be astonishingly faster and safer too.

Comment: Thank you. When you write that the `join`command does not alter the order of characters in memory and it is an issue of rendering text on the screen, do you mean the the result of the `join` in memory and as used to build the SQL statement should be correctly ordered also?  If so, then the SQL should not error and I must have another error I'm missing elsewhere.